# Display table caption tag inside table

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to make the border and background of a table to go around the caption tag, rather than excluding it for accessibility reasons. I was it to display similar to a th tag.

I've tried to add and remove borders, but the border and background styles are in a stylesheet I don't want to alter (or duplicate), making this challenging.

```
<table class="border-background-stylesheet">
<caption>Caption</caption>
<tr><th colspan="2">What I want caption to look like</th></tr>
<tr><td>Data cell</td><td>Data cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

Example:

```css
.border-background-stylesheet {
  border:#222222;
  background:#00EE00;
}
```

```html
    <table class="border-background-stylesheet">
    <caption>Caption</caption>
    <tr><th colspan="100">What I want caption to look like</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Data cell</td><td>Data cell</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You should add your `.border-background-stylesheet` css into your question (even better if you replaced your code block with a snippet that includes that css).

Comment: @benvc Does what I added work?

Comment: @BrandonFowler - Hit the big blue button, you tell me! (it does work)

Comment: @enhzflep Oh wow, that's really cool. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonFowler - it's basically like JSFiddle - but right here on the page. Just hover the icons while you're posting and you'll work out which one does it (I use it rarely and forget, so just hover them whenever I need the functionality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to fulfil the requirement:

Basically, border the whole table, then remove it from the top.
Next, border the whole caption, then remove it from the bottom.

Result? Two blocks that appear as just one.

```css
.border-background-stylesheet
{
 background:#00EE00;
 border: solid 1px black;
 border-top: none;
}

caption
{
 background:#00EE00;
 border: solid 1px black;
 border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="border-background-stylesheet">
<caption>Caption</caption>
<tr><th>What I want caption to look like</tr></th>
</table>
```

Comment: I was looking for a way where I do not need to have separate CSS for the caption, at least when it comes to background and border CSS

Comment: Well, they're 2 separate elements and as far as I know designed not to be rendered in the manner you'd like, thus the CSS tom-foolery. Sorry! Wait for a while and see if you get a better answer. Accepting an answer is often a bit poisonous when it comes to getting new contributions.